# What chemicals are going to be used to make the smoke black or white?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, color

For the papal election, white and black smoke will be used to signal success or failure in the voting process.

From what I understand, the ballots are burnt and chemicals are added to create the color.

But what chemicals are used to get black or white smoke?

Comment: I think Titanium Tetrachloride http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium_tetrachloride would be a good option for white smoke (I've heard it's used quite often in smoke bombs).

Comment: This link could also be useful: http://thehappyscientist.com/science-experiment/black-and-white-smoke

Comment: @kaliaden, I read that link before posting, and it was an interesting read. But wouldn't Titanium tetrachloride be ruled out as poisonous?

Comment: It is quite dangerous because of the corrosive fumes released. But the link mentions that they have experimented with lots of (not especially safe) stuff before, so I wouldn't rule it out completely :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Titanium Tetrachloride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium_tetrachloride) would be a good option for white smoke (I've heard it's used quite often in smoke bombs). But it releases quite a lot of $HCl$ gas and so it might not be very safe.

A quick Google search comes up with a lot of answers to your question though. This site even answers your question in the same context (The elections going on at the Vatican):

http://thehappyscientist.com/science-experiment/black-and-white-smoke

Apparently you can make white smoke using Magnesium powder as well. (The white colour is due to fine particles of Magnesium Oxide $MgO$ )

It seems the Vatican has experimented using many sources before (Military flares, Smoke bombs and so on) though apparently they didn't turn out too well...

**EDIT**

The Wikipedia article on [Coloured smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored_smoke) gives another possibility. You can add Titanium Dioxide ($TiO_2$) to a mixture of Potassium Chlorate ($KClO_3$) and Lactose for white smoke. $KClO_3$ is a powerful oxidizing agent which reacts with Lactose (which is a reducing sugar) to create an explosion. $TiO_2$ is safe and is used as a pigment in most white paints and as a food colouring as well.

**EDIT2**

The official recipes have been revealed by the Vatican press office. See [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/13/science/vatican-reveals-recipes-for-conclave-smoke.html?_r=0) story on the New York Times website.

The previous edit was partially correct. They use a mixture of $KClO_3$, lactose and pine rosin for white smoke. For black smoke, they use Potassium perchlorate ($KClO_4$), anthracene (an aromatic compound made of three fused benzene rings) and sulfur.

The process (quoted from the site):

"The chemicals are electrically ignited in a special stove first used for the conclave of 2005, the statement said. The stove sits in the Sistine Chapel next to an older stove in which the ballots are burned; the colored smoke and the smoke from the ballots mix and travel up a long copper flue to the chapel roof, where the smoke is visible from St. Peter’s Square. A resistance wire is used to preheat the flue so it draws properly, and the flue has a fan as a backup to ensure that no smoke enters the chapel."

Comment: I just saw that NYT article, and was about to post that information as an answer. I'm glad to see someone beat me to it.

Comment: I suppose I was just in time.. I never thought we'd see the white smoke recipe in action so soon. :) We now have a new Pope (who already has a Wikipedia page within half an hour after being announced!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Francis